# Crawling dynamic publishing pages and assets

Tags: search, fast-search, crawl

i got the following search requirements for a public internet site based on SharePoint 2010

- publishing pages must be indexed
- Documents must be indexed
- Only documents being linked on at least one page should be found, others are hidden.

Is that possible using Enterprise Search or FAST? How can unlinked documents automatically be hidden from the search results?

Thanks!

Comment: For this, I would just probably index the site as HTTP only. But you can create a filter with scopes to block out certain fields quite easily. I would lean towards HTTP only for a front facing website with these requirements anyway.